# CMake - Visual Studio project dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, cmake

### In few words

My question is: Is there a way for generating a visual studio solutions that contains a project, for which I'm writing the CMake, and another project, for which the CMake is already available?

I was thinking about using `add_subdirectory`, but I'm not sure this is the best solution and the meaning of the parameter `binary_dir` is not really clear to me.

### More in details

I have a Visual Studio project (B) which depends on another one (A).
I've written the CMakeLists for A and I'm able of generating the VS project and compiling it.

I've written a CMakeLists for B. I'm able to configure the VS project for B in such a way that it can access the headers and the libraries of A. Everything compiles.

```
A
- CMakeLists.txt
- src
  - *.cpp

B 
- CMakeLists.txt
- src
  - *.cpp

Build
- Build_A
- Build_B
```

However when I change something in A, from the B project (that's possible because with visual studio I can access the headers of A from the project B), and I try to compile, A is not compiled.

The project B compiles only B.

I was able to improve the situation by using `add_subdirectory`. In the CMakeLists of B I included the following line:

```
add_subdirectory(PATH_TO_A  A)
```

However with this solutions there is a duplication of the compilation files of A. They are generated in the out-of-source build directory `BUILD_A` when I compile from the project A; and they are generated in the out-of-source build directory `BUILD_B\A` when I compile from the project B.

What's the best practice for including the A project in the solution generated from the CMakeLists of B and avoid duplication of compilation files?

P.S.
If possible I would like to avoid the need of recompiling everything twice. That is, If I have compiled A and I need to compile B for the first time I would like to avoid the need of recompiling A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle using `add_subdirectory` is a good way to solve this.

A CMake project that can be compiled on its own can also be compiled as a subproject, if it follows a few rules. First of all, any change to the global state will of course also affect all other projects being built from the same root. Aggressive changes to the global build environment are likely to disturb other projects and should be avoided.

Additionally, a project that is being pulled in like this must not assume that its CMakeLists file is the root of the build. For instance, the [CMAKE_BINARY_DIR](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_BINARY_DIR) variable always points to the top-level binary directory, while the [PROJECT_BINARY_DIR](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable%3aPROJECT_BINARY_DIR) points to the binary directory of the most recent project. A library that always assumes it's being built as a top-level binary may use those two interchangeably. A library that can be built both on its own or as a sub-project must be aware of the difference.

Note that `add_subdirectory` introduces a tight coupling between the projects and only works well if both involved projects behave accordingly.

A more loosely coupled alternative would be to include the dependency as an [ExternalProject](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#module%3aExternalProject), but from what you wrote in the question (project should automatically recompile if source of the dependency changes), `add_subdirectory` seems the better match for you.

Comment: Thanks, this works. However I have a problem. I defined an out-of-source build folder for A and another for B. In the build folder of B, there is now a new directory (which correspond to the name I gave to the parameter `binary_dir` of the command `add_subdirectory`). Now if a compile from the project A the release folder is generated in the build directory of A. However if I compile from the project B, the release folder is generated in the `binary_dir` contained in the build directory of B. Basically I would like to avoid this duplication of compilation files. Is that possible?

Comment: @Maverik This is the tradeoff: If you compile separately, you get the files twice. You could theoretically merge the binary output directories for both builds, but I would not recommend this. If you want the files only once, split the projects and have the dependency included as an external project or as an imported target, but not in source form.

Comment: What do you mean by split the projects? Having them in two separated solution? Actually I would like to have a solution with project A, and another one with projects A and B. Alternatively, How can I import a target? Thanks!

Comment: @Maverik If you have a complete subproject (one that can also be built stand-alone, with its own `project` call) as part of your main project's directory tree and pull that in with `add_subdirectory` you will get a separate solution for that project in a subdirectory of the binary dir by default (that is, unless specifying a binary directory manually). Those two solutions share output directories for the respective subproject, so no file duplication. If you organize your solutions in another (non-hierarchical) way, this will no longer work without fiddling with the binary dirs manually.